# Nested Dictionary to Dataframe (by different depth of dict)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have such a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'Гидротехническое оборудование':{'Гидравлическая турбина':{'Энергетические характеристики': 0.2,
                                                                    'Срок службы': 0.8}},
                                   
         'Сооружения':{'Кабельная линия электропередачи':{'Общие сведения':1}},
                                   
         'Тепломеханическое оборудование':{'Паровая турбина':{'Состояние масла':0.164,
                                                              'Срок службы':0.539,
                                                              'Тепловые расширения':0.297},
                                           'Паровой котел':{'Паропроизводительность':0.5,'Срок службы':0.5}
                                          },
                                   
         'Электротехническое оборудование':{'Гидрогенератор':{'Срок службы':0.8,'Общие сведения':0.2},
                                           'Трансформатор (автотрансформатор) силовой':{'Общие сведения':1},
                                           'Турбогенератор':{'Общие сведения':1}
                                           }
        }
```

It is necessary to convert it to a pandas DataFrame. The final result should be as follows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvLci.png)

Comment: this dictionary posted above is incorrect in its format.  please amend this.

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and refrase your question.

Answer (score -1):

this is populated in the dataframe in the same way. (Pandas interprets the nesting as a multilayer unless otherwise specified).

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

table_6 = {'Гидротехническое оборудование':{'Гидравлическая турбина':{'Энергетические характеристики': 0.2, 'Срок службы': 0.8}},

         'Сооружения':{'Кабельная линия электропередачи':{'Общие сведения':1}},
                                   
         'Тепломеханическое оборудование':{'Паровая турбина':{'Состояние масла':0.164,
                                                              'Срок службы':0.539,
                                                              'Тепловые расширения':0.297},
                                           'Паровой котел':{'Паропроизводительность':0.5,'Срок службы':0.5}
                                          },
                                   
         'Электротехническое оборудование':{'Гидрогенератор':{'Срок службы':0.8,'Общие сведения':0.2},
                                           'Трансформатор (автотрансформатор) силовой':{'Общие сведения':1},
                                           'Турбогенератор':{'Общие сведения':1}
                                           }
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(table_6)

print(df)
```

output:

```
                                                               Гидротехническое оборудование  ...              Электротехническое оборудование
Гидравлическая турбина                     {'Энергетические характеристики': 0.2, 'Срок с...  ...
NaN
Кабельная линия электропередачи                                                          NaN  ...
NaN
Паровая турбина                                                                          NaN  ...
NaN
Паровой котел                                                                            NaN  ...
NaN
Гидрогенератор                                                                           NaN  ...  {'Срок службы': 0.8, 'Общие сведения': 0.2}
Трансформатор (автотрансформатор) силовой                                                NaN  ...                        {'Общие сведения': 1}
Турбогенератор                                                                           NaN  ...                        {'Общие сведения': 1}

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```

Do you wish to do something with the nesting ?
(probably a separate question if so).